# absolute numbers subtractor

Tags: digital-logic

I have to subtract two binary numbers, each two bits long.

so the numbers are x0x1 and y0y1. the result z0z1 has to be the absolute value.

At my disposal are: a two bit subtractor (ie it subtracts two numbers of two bits each and puts out two bits which is the result)

I also have a magnitude comparator for two number each two bits.

The magnitude comparator has three outputs:
x > y, x = y, x < y

I also have 4 xor gates.

I figured the best way to approach this problem is to let the subtractor do the subtraction and if y0y1 > x0x1 then swap the inputs to the subtractor.

I'm thinking that I have to somehow use the 4 xor gates and the magnitude comparator to do the switching if the case above is true. but I can't figure out how.

Comment: so, you need to subtract two numbers, and you have a subtractor. I'd say you're done, or you haven't told us everything about that subtractor. Also, these are a whole lot of 16 possible x - y combinations, so frankly, write a table, use as LUT or find minterms, be done. This exercise is extremely awkward.

Comment: I assume your inputs are positive-valued, not 2's-complement. (For 2s-complement your adder would need 3 outputs.) The fact that you have 4 XORs leads me to think that you must apply them at the inputs rather than at the outputs. That means that the only source for the invert/not-invert is the comparator, with the inputs as input. Does that help?

Comment: I removed the "here is my question", because it's redundant, and I removed the "thank you" phrase, because it's also redundant. Using such phrases is frowned upon here, because it distracts from the question. Please don't add them back.

Comment: @marcus I thgink you missed the clause "the result z0z1 has to be the absolute value."

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I have a subtractor but I need the absolute value, basically if x > y then I need to do y - x instead of x -y. that way I get the absolute value. in order to do this switching I have 4 xor gates and a magnitude comparator.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen actually, I didn't – if I had two bit variables, there's no reason to assume we're doing 2's complement. So, it's reasonable to assume the subtractor only serves positive outputs, and is undefined on x-y<0; or that the subtractor actually gives abs values directly. Either way needs to be specified.

Comment: @eventhorizon02 so, what does your subtractor *do* if you give it x<y? What is the value for `x=00`, `y=10`, for example?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I don't really care what the subtractor does if x<y, my problem is making sure that if x < y then I swap the inputs so x is always the bigger one. I have a magnitude comparator with 3 outputs x=y, x<y and x>y and also I have 4 xor gates.

Comment: @eventhorizon02 I just gave you a hint. If your subtractor does the right thing, then the solution is *not* to swap the inputs.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I also think that I have to use the comparator and the xor gates at the input but the question is how.and the numbers are not 2's complement or negative, just positive 2 bit numbers.

Comment: @EH02 Come on, how many options do you have? I can think of only one.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen still can't figure it out.

Comment: Start thinking! 1) You have a magnitude comparator, what could you compare? 2) You have a subtractor, but only for the X >= Y case. How can you get from the general case to that restricted case?

Comment: yes, I have the magnitude comparator and I can use it to compare the two numbers and know which one is bigger, I also have the 4 xor gates. I want to always get the bigger number into the x of the subtractor and the smaller one into the y.

Comment: @eventhorizon02 Use the (X<Y) output to tie to one input of all four of your XORs. The other input of each XOR comes from X0, X1, Y0 and Y1. The outputs of the XORs go to your subtractor, appropriately. Done.

Comment: Is this a school assignment of some sort?

Comment: @jonk not sure I get your answer. so each xor has the same 5 inputs? or did you mean that first one has x<y, x0 and y0 then second xor has x<y ,x1 and y1 and so fourth. that doesn't work though.

Comment: @eventhorizon02 You have 4 XORs (I assume 2-in, each.) One of the inputs of each XOR gets the output of (X<Y). That uses up four inputs (one from each XOR) so there is one input from each XOR left over. Now feed each of the four X and Y bits to the remaining XOR inputs. The outputs of each XOR can be considered X* and Y*. Feed X* and Y* to your subtractor.

Comment: @jonk so lets say that the inputs of X1X0 = 00 and Y1Y0 = 01, in this case x<y will be 1. so xor number one will get 0 from X0 and a 1 from x<y. the output of xor number one  will be 1 but which is wrong because the x0 entrance of the subtractor still supposed to be 0 in this case since both x0 and y0 are 0

Comment: @jonk you can have more than two inputs to the xors if needed

Comment: @eventhorizon02 Feed \$\vec{X}\$ and \$\vec{Y}\$ into the comparator. Feed \$\vec{X}\$ into two XORs, leaving two inputs free (one of each XOR.) The outputs of the these XOR is \$\vec{X^\*}\$. Feed \$\vec{Y}\$ into two more XORs, leaving two more inputs free. The outputs of these XORs is \$\vec{Y^\*}\$. The output of the comparator's \$X<Y\$ output is tied in common to all four of these free XOR inputs. Feed \$\vec{X^\*}\$ and \$\vec{Y^\*}\$ into your subtractor. The output of the subtractor is the absolute value of the difference, or \$\mid X - Y\mid\$. I can't get any clearer. And it works.

Comment: @eventhorizon02 See: https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/n3z24237y6s9/two-bit-absolute-magnitude-v1/ and https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/n8j4z92uej29/two-bit-absolute-magnitude-v2/ for two different renditions. Then create some tables.

Comment: @jonk I get it now! you are not actually swapping the inputs to the subtractor. In case of x<y you are making both numbers the 2's complement and if (! x<y) they stay the same. yes that works.Thanks a bunch. if you want to add it as an answer I'll select it. thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the schematic I'd been discussing:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ162H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It was just a matter of inverting the inputs, based upon the comparison output.

It's a little excessive to do it that way, but also pretty obvious when you think about it. (I gather those were the parts you are given to work with.)

A simplification isn't too difficult:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4Jw08.png)</sup>

But it is a little bit less obvious, until you look at the algebra (or table.)

Comment: yes, it's basically using the fact that A-B = (-A)-(-B). why didn't I think about that. Thank you very much!

Comment: @eventhorizon02 I'm sure you won't forget it, now! Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have 16 possible cases, it might be easier to do this with a lookup.

Even if not, write out the whole truth table.  It's only 16 lines, with a 2-bit output for each line.  Then think of this as a stricly combunatorial function.  See if you can simplify things.  Look at the function for each output bit separately.  Maybe a few simplifications emerge.  If not fall back to the lookup.

You also need to specify the format of the input values.  Are they 2s complement and can be negative or not, for example.

Comment: I have a subtractor that takes two numbers and and outputs the subtraction result, the numbers are two bit each. so no need for two's complement. I also have a magnitude comparator that compares two numbers. the comparator has 3 output legs: the legs are one for x>y one for x<y and one for x=y. I also have 4 xor gates. I need to somehow use the comparator and the 4 xor gates so that the subtractor always has in its x input the bigger number.